# Using Shell.NameSpace on directory that doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, null, directory, file-exists

When you use `$shell.namespace()` on a directory that doesn't exist, you get back a null object. Is there anyway to have the shell automatically create the directory if it doesn't exist, thereby not getting a null.

Answer (score 1):

Typicall scenario is:

```
if (-not (test-path $directoryPath ))
{
   New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPath
}
```